# Java Generic Comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator

```
public class arr<T>
{
    class comp <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T>
    {
        public int compare(T lObj,T rObj)
        {
              return lObj.compareTo(rObj);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<T> list;
    Comparator<T> comparator;
    public arr()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
        comparator = new comp();
    }
    public void add(T data)
    {
        list.add(data);         
    }
    public int getLength()
    {
        return list.size();
    }
    public T get(int index)
    {
        return list.get(index);
    }
    public void sort()
    {
        list.sort(comparator);
    }
}
```

Hello, I am trying to make the sort function work but have a problem.
In the *arr* constructor, if I write

```
comparator = new comp<T>();
```

it gives me an error saying

```
"type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2 comparator = 
new comp<T>();                            ^
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in class arr
T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class arr.comp"
```

And if I take out the type and write like this

```
comparator = new comp;
```

then it does work but gives me a warning that says

```
warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: arr.comp
comparator = new comp();
```

I can see what it means by raw types. I am not specifying the type, but somehow it works and if I try to fix the warning by specifying the type then, it throws an error. Could you please help me figure it out? I know... I am a noob my code must be a pain in your eyes. I am playing with generic comparators and trying many things to get familiar. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you running `new comp<T>`? That `T` type wouldn't exist outside your classes here, and if it does, it must be an otherwise Comparable type. Also, `new comp;` just doesn't compile, you need parenthesis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is confusing you, because the `T` defined by `comp` is *hiding* the `T` defined by `arr`. For the explanation below, I'll call them `Tcomp` and `Tarr`.

`Tcomp` is required to extend `Comparable`, but `Tarr` isn't required to do so, which means that `Tarr` cannot be "mapped" to `Tcomp`.

To fix, change `Tarr` so it is also required to extend `Comparable`:

```
public class arr<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

---

*On a side note:*
You `comp` class is an inner class, but it doesn't use anything from the outer class, so it should be a static nested class:

```
static class comp<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T>
```

Alternatively, leave `comp` as an inner class, and let it reuse the `T` from the outer class:

```
class arr<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    class comp implements Comparator<T>
```

But, since Java (8 or higher) comes with an implementation of `Comparator` for comparing `Comparable` objects, you should use it:

```
public class arr<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    ArrayList<T> list;
    Comparator<T> comparator;
    public arr()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
        comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation!

Comment: @pizza If this answers your question, you should click the check mark next to the question, so others can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.